# How to insert or update database using a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview whereby i want to insert data into database.If the data exist then it should be updated.And also the last column of the datagridview when i click it should change from datagridviewtextbox to datagridviewcomboboxcell.
[how can i insert or update data into the datagridview and when i click the last column it should change from datagridviewtextbox to datagridviewcomboboxcell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFaIw.png)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows

            If Not row.IsNewRow Then

                sqlSTR = "SELECT        ID, Code, SubjectName, Abbrev, Category FROM TBL_SubjectReg WHERE        (Code = '" & row.Cells(0).Value & "')"
                ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

                If sqlDT.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    sqlSTR = "UPDATE       TBL_SubjectReg SET                Code ='" & row.Cells(0).Value & "', SubjectName ='" & row.Cells(1).Value & "', Abbrev ='" & row.Cells(2).Value & "', Category ='" & row.Cells(3).Value & "' WHERE        (Code = '" & row.Cells(0).Value & "')"
                    ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

                    MsgBox("Record updated successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")

                    Exit Sub

                Else

                    sqlSTR = "INSERT INTO TBL_SubjectReg (Code, SubjectName, Abbrev, Category) VALUES ('" & row.Cells(0).Value & "','" & row.Cells(1).Value & "','" & row.Cells(2).Value & "','" & row.Cells(3).Value & "')"
                    ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlSTR)

                    'MsgBox("Record saved successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Record")

                    'Exit Sub

                End If

            End If

        Next


    End Sub
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Why only selected rows? If your use a datatable that will figure out for you what rows are new and what rows are updated. Then you can call update on a dataadapter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should throw all that code away and start again with:

- add a new DataSet type item to your project
- open the DataSet by double clicking
- right click on the design surface and choose New TableAdapter
- pick a conncetionstring or create a connection and store it in the app settings, put a query of `SELECT * FROM tbl_SubjectReg where Code = @code` into the wizard, call the query FillByCode/GetDataByCode
- finish the wizard, save the dataset
- open the Data Sources window (view menu, other windows)
- expand the nodes in the datasources window, drag the tbl_SubjectGrid node onto the form
- a toolstrip with a textbox and search button appear, for you to type the code in. a datagrid appears, already properly bound to the dataset/datatable through a binding source. a tableadapter appears, and code that uses it to fill the grid is written

Run the project; put a code in the box, click the button, edit the data, click the floppy disk - it is saved. Add a new row; save it too

Work from this as a base; it's taken ab out 1 minute to create something that is miles better than the code you've already got there (for reasons like: resistant to sql injection, properly uses MVC concepts to separate data from presentation, it works...)